# Leer un JSON mediante una URL en PHP

Tags: php, json, jsonobject, jsonarray, jsonp

Tengo este código para obtener datos de un *JSON*:

```
$url = "json";
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
$prueba = json_decode($xml,true);
print_r($prueba);
```

Esto me imprime este array. Usando varios métodos no lo logro leer:

```
Array (  
  [consultarResponse] => Array (  
    [return] => Array (  
      [coResultado] => 0000 [datosPersona] => Array (  
        [apPrimer] => MERCEDES  
        [apSegundo] => REYES  
        [direccion] => AV.CESAR VALLEJO 1126  
        [estadoCivil] => SOLTERO  
        [foto] => /9j/4AAQSkZJKTPYUtAz/2Q==  
        [prenombres] => HILMAR ALEXIS  
        [restriccion] => NINGUNA  
        [ubigeo] => LA LIBERTAD/TRUJILLO/TRUJILLO  
      )  
      [deResultado] => Consulta realizada correctamente  
    )  
  )  
)
```

Comment: ¿Cómo intentas leerlo y qué imprime o qué errores tienes? ¿Te devuelve datos de una sola persona o puede devolver datos de varias personas? ¿Cómo quieres que salgan los datos por pantalla?

Comment: Quiero leer los datos de apPrimer, apSegundo y etc pero no logro recorrerlo

Answer (score 0):

y si lo intentas de esta manera ?

```
       $url = "url.json";
       $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);

       foreach($data as $d){
           //Imprimes la informacion.
       }
```

Si no es un archivo .json y es un archivo .php

solo verifica que al inicio del archivo este lo siguiente

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

y después a la respuesta de tu consulta la muestras con un echo y con la función json_encode

```
echo json_encode($respuesta);
```

Comment: Me muestra error dice ques es un tipo objeto JSON

Comment: Ese array me ejecuta pero no logro recorrerlo.

Comment: para recorrerlo debes poner algo asi echo $d['consultarResponse']['coResultado']['datosPersona']['apPrimer']

Comment: Undefined index: consultarResponse in algo no me sale

Comment: pon esto: var_dump($data);  y te debe de mostrar las posiciones que debes de recorrer. Me muestras alguna captura de lo que te arroje.

Comment: array(1) { ["consultarResponse"]=> array(1) { ["return"]=> array(3) { ["coResultado"]=> string(4) "0000" ["datosPersona"]=> array(8) { ["apPrimer"]=> string(8) "MERCEDES" ["apSegundo"]=> string(5) "REYES" ["direccion"]=> string(21) "AV.CESAR VALLEJO 1126" ["estadoCivil"]=> string(7) "SOLTERO" ["foto"]=> string(9520) "/9j/4AAQSkZJ" ["prenombres"]=> string(13) "HILMAR ALEXIS" ["restriccion"]=> string(7) "NINGUNA" ["ubigeo"]=> string(29) "LA LIBERTAD/TRUJILLO/TRUJILLO" } ["deResultado"]=> string(32) "Consulta realizada correctamente" } } }

Comment: si es solo un dato lo que te mostrará, no uses el foreach, intenta imprimirlo de esta forma: $data['consultarResponse']['coResultado']['datosPersona']['apPrimer'];

Comment: Si como es un array dentro de otro array quiero recorrer los datos de un array donde tiene el contenido apPrimer, apSegundo y etc y no logro mostrar